# Need to get the messages between the user identified by LoginId and others

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named messages.

It has 4 columns ( date_msg , id_sender , id_receiver , msg ). `$lgn_id` is a variable that contains the login Id. I want to show the latest messages between the person logged in and other persons.

this is how the table look

```
id_sender---------id_receiver---------date_msg-----------------------------------msg

3-------------------- 2--------------------2016-01-30 07:11:08--------------------bonjour

1-------------------- 3--------------------2016-01-30 09:11:00--------------------mar7aba kifak

1-------------------- 2--------------------2016-01-30 11:00:00--------------------hi kifik fena nt3rf

2-------------------- 1--------------------2016-01-30 11:02:02--------------------eh ahlen ana sara

1-------------------- 2--------------------2016-01-30 11:08:14--------------------w ana ali knt bede

2-------------------- 1--------------------2016-01-30 13:20:13--------------------eh s2alne aya jem3a
```

I tried to run this query:

```
SELECT * from messages where id_sender='$lgn_id' or d_receiver='$lgn_id'
```

and got this results

```
id_sender---------id_receiver---------date_msg-----------------------------------msg

3-------------------- 2--------------------2016-01-30 07:11:08--------------------bonjour

1-------------------- 2--------------------2016-01-30 11:00:00--------------------hi kifik fena nt3rf

2-------------------- 1--------------------2016-01-30 11:02:02--------------------eh ahlen ana sara

1-------------------- 2--------------------2016-01-30 11:08:14--------------------w ana ali knt bede

2-------------------- 1--------------------2016-01-30 13:20:13--------------------eh s2alne aya jem3a bad
```

If I am currently logged in with `$lgn_id = 2` and I want to have lines 1 and 6 of the latest message with another person, how can I get it?

Comment: Please dont put pictures into your question. Paste the data, pictures tend to disappear and the question may not

Comment: sorry i'am new to the website i will stop putting pictures to the question

Comment: Please replace the pictures otherwise someone is going to close this questions, or you will get downvoted

Comment: Replace `or` with `AND`

Comment: i replaced them thank you for the advice

Comment: if i put and no results are found because lgn_id is either sender or receiver in every line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
    (SELECT * from messages where id_sender='$lgn_id' order by date_msg desc limit 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * from messages where id_receiver='$lgn_id' order by date_msg desc limit 1)
```

in case if you want them joined that is how it goes

```
    SELECT Msg1.id_sender, Msg1.id_receiver Msg1.date_msg, Msg2.id_sender, Msg2.id_receiver, Msg2.date_msg 
    FROM messages Msg1 join messages Msg2 
    WHERE Msg1.id_receiver=Msg2.id_sender and Msg1.id_receiver='$lgn_id' or Msg2.id_sender='$lgn_id' order by date_msg desc limit 1
```

Comment: and provide me with the feedbacks please

Comment: it gave me latest of sender 1 receiver 2
latest sender 2 receiver one
i want them also joined because it's a message between same person

Comment: you don't want them join because they are 2 separate rows of the same columns

Comment: but the 2 3 first line did not shown so it not taking rows when only 1 msg is sent

Comment: i did it before but then i lost my project and now i am rebuilding it 
it is possible i just can't remember how i did it

Comment: I didn't say it is not possible I am saying it not right to do it

Comment: i have to the only way i can think of

Comment: ok I ll do it, you are new here, when I provide you with the answer that fits your need you should accept my answer that is how the things go on here deal ?

Comment: yes i know if you provide me with the answer i should turn green check for you
SELECT * from (SELECT * from messages order by date_msg DESC ) t where id_sender='$lgn_id' or id_receiver='$lgn_id' group by id_sender,id_receiver 
i tried this and so far it is near the answer show me latest msg but still 1 2 and 2 1 essue

Comment: i correct it Msg1.date_msg for the order
but 1 problem still occurs line where id 3 send msg to id 2 not appering

Comment: thank you for trying , since you are so close i will give you the answer green check and will continue from here figuring out the rest